# import from file in javascript

Tags: ajax, file-upload

I have a html/javascript table/grid that I need to import data from a file, this is not possible without serverside.  So I decides to have a FileEcho server that takes a file upload from the table/grid, the problem is I don't want to refresh the page afterwards, it's a multipart request, not an ajax request.  Is it possible to up the file ajax style?
how can this be done? any solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A popular way is to do the file upload in an `iframe` (you can set the `<form>`'s `target` attribute to the `name` attribute of your `iframe`)

You can attach an `onload` event on the `iframe` to find out when the data has been echoed from the server. From there, you can grab the `contentDocument` attribute from the `iframe` object in javascript (from there you could look at the `innerHTML` content of the `contentDocument.body` to see the data).

Just note that in IE, you have to use `document.frames['frame_name'].document` instead of `iframeObject.contentDocument`

See these articles for more info:

- http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-file-upload-tutorial.html
- http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax/ajax_file_upload/